# Trying to run Selenium in python shell

Tags: python, selenium

After successfully installing selenium at the command line prompt using - pip install selenium
I get the following error code after typing 'from selenium import webdriver' into the python shell (idle)

File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in 
from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: If you are on mac system try sudo installing selenium

Comment: thanks, but on PC Win10